# How to set .js for some id or div?

Tags: javascript, html

.....................................................................................................................................................................

How to set .js for some id or div ?

.....................................................................................................................................................................

Like use

```
<script src="jquery_load_more.js"></script>
```

for `<div id="1">`

And use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-selectify.js"></script>
```

for `<div id="2">` only , how can i set ?

Comment: Don't use different files, use different [functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp). And: [Learn Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/).

Comment: dig for knowledge at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/learn/javascript  :D

Comment: If you want to make changes to an id/div, call them by their div names/id names in a JS function.

Comment: Cecil - please show me some demo . thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attaching a external js file to your document which is fine but so far you haven't told it to do anything (or at least from what you have shown).

There are 2 main ways of doing this (there are other ways but I tend to use JQuery or Plain Javascript)

if you are using JQuery you need to attach the JQuery file as well as the file you have already attached use a cdn if you don't want to download it

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

(add the http before the //)

then you can call the element you want to add the style to by:

`$('#<ELEMENT_NAME>') this is using a # for the id you can use a . for the elements class`

if you choose to use Javascript and not JQuery then try something like this:

`<script>  function myFunction()  {  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hello           world";  }  </script>`

Good Luck and happy coding :)

Comment: No problem but give me a little bit more information on what you are trying to achive. please

Comment: i want to use `<script src="jquery_load_more.js"></script>` for content in `<div id="1">` only and use `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` for content in `<div id="2">` only

Comment: the 2 examples you have used both require that you include a jquery library first, so use my example above to include this and make sure you include it before your code (it needs to call the library first). then your code should work fine you then need to call the element inside your code $('#1') will call the div with id 1 $('#2') will call the div with id 2 you then need to tell it what to do. please let us know what you want to achieve with the element :)

Comment: Sorry no jsfiddle will let you show the js code but since you haven't given any description of what you want to do with the 2 elements I can not demo it, you only need to write the $('#1') code inside the first attached file and $('#2') code inside the 2nd attached file then one will look for the element with id 1 and the other will look for the element with id 2 but if you need further help you will need to write a more descriptive summary of what you are trying to achieve. thanks

Comment: `<script src="jquery_load_more.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
var page = 1;
var pages = $("#pages").val(); //TOTAL NUMBER OF PAGES

$("#content_grid_big").load("results.php");
//WHEN THE 'LOAD MORE' BUTTON IS PRESSED
$("#loadmore").live("click", function(){
var next = page+=1;

$.get("results.php?page="+next, function(data){
if(next==pages){
$("#loadmore").remove(); //IF ALL PAGES ARE LOADED, THE BUTTON WILL BE REMOVED
}
$("#content_grid_big").append(data); //LOADS THE NEW PAGE OF CONTENT UNDER THE REST
});
});
});
</script>`